# Spring webflow - invoke method on each refresh (request)

Tags: spring-webflow

How to invoke bean-action method on each refresh?
I put it into render-actions, but it not helps:

```
    <render-actions>
       <bean-action bean="personService" method="getPerson">
        <method-arguments>
            <argument
                    expression="flowScope.personId"
                    parameter-type="java.lang.Long" />
        </method-arguments>
        <method-result name="person" scope="flow" />
       </bean-action>
    </render-actions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: need to add "redirect:" to view param in view-state, so in this case render-actions will be executed on each refresh (request), so complete code is:

```
<view-state id="browsePersonForm" view="redirect:personInfo">
    <render-actions>
       <bean-action bean="personService" method="getPerson">
        <method-arguments>
            <argument
                    expression="flowScope.personId"
                    parameter-type="java.lang.Long" />
        </method-arguments>
        <method-result name="person" scope="request" />
       </bean-action>
    </render-actions>
</view-state>
```